# Oracle SQL query. How to obtain string tokens from a string using 'space' as a delimiter, then display selective tokens?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

E.g. I have a table - USERS, with column NAME1 varchar2(30). Records currently in it are:

```
NAME1:
Benjamin Barker
Alexis Jacob Alexander Cruise
Christopher James Lee
```

How do I create a function or write a query where I can get the output as follows:

```
Benjamin ****
Alexis **** Cruise
Christopher **** Lee
```

The function/query will calculate the name string and return E.g. `'Benjamin barker'` as 2 tokens, but only display the first token. While if the name has three or more tokens, e.g. `'Christopher James Lee'` or `'Alexis Jacob Alexander Cruise'`, it will only display the first and the last token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `instr` to locate the spaces and `substr` to extract the tokens, with some conditional logic:

```
-- CTE for your sample data
with users (name1) as (
            select 'Benjamin Barker' from dual
  union all select 'Alexis Jacob Alexander Cruise' from dual
  union all select 'Christopher James Lee' from dual
  union all select 'Madonna' from dual
)
-- actual query
select case
         when instr(name1, ' ') = 0
         then name1
         else substr(name1, 1, instr(name1, ' ') - 1)
       end
    || case
         when instr(name1, ' ', 1, 2) > 0
         then substr(name1, instr(name1, ' ', -1))
       end
    as result
from users;

RESULT                                                    
----------------------------------------------------------
Benjamin
Alexis Cruise
Christopher Lee
Madonna
```

If you actually want the `****` as shown in the question you can concatenate that in the first `else` clause:

```
select case
         when instr(name1, ' ') = 0
         then name1
         else substr(name1, 1, instr(name1, ' ') - 1) || ' ****'
       end
    || case
         when instr(name1, ' ', 1, 2) > 0
         then substr(name1, instr(name1, ' ', -1))
       end
    as result
from users;

RESULT                                                         
---------------------------------------------------------------
Benjamin ****
Alexis **** Cruise
Christopher **** Lee
Madonna
```

or if you want to add `+ Masked` as you said in a comment, only to those that are actually changed, you can just concatenate a third case expression:

```
select case
         when instr(name1, ' ') = 0
         then name1
         else substr(name1, 1, instr(name1, ' ') - 1)
       end
    || case
         when instr(name1, ' ', 1, 2) > 0
         then substr(name1, instr(name1, ' ', -1))
       end
    || case
         when instr(name1, ' ', 1, 1) > 0
         then ' + Masked'
       end
    as result
from users;

RESULT                                                             
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Benjamin + Masked
Alexis Cruise + Masked
Christopher Lee + Masked
Madonna
```

---

If you want it in a function, just use the same case expressions:

```
create or replace function short_name (p_name varchar2)
return varchar2 as
begin
  return case
           when instr(p_name, ' ') = 0
           then p_name
           else substr(p_name, 1, instr(p_name, ' ') - 1)
         end
      || case
           when instr(p_name, ' ', 1, 2) > 0
           then substr(p_name, instr(p_name, ' ', -1))
         end
      || case
           when instr(p_name, ' ', 1, 1) > 0
           then ' + Masked'
         end;
end short_name;
/

select short_name(name1) as result from users;

RESULT                        
------------------------------
Benjamin + Masked
Alexis Cruise + Masked
Christopher Lee + Masked
Madonna
```

Comment: Thank you very much! this worked perfectly! sorry can I ask if you were store this into a function how would you do it?

Comment: @Jason - well, I probably wouldn't, but if you needed to then just create a function that accepts and returns `varchar2`, maybe inside a package; and in the body return the result of the case expression. I've added an example of a standalone function.

Comment: okay! got it, thank you for your guidance. One last question, i wish to add a string text ' + Masked' at the end of the result displayed.  e.g. 'Benjamin + Masked', 'Alexis Cruise + Masked', etc...   I have tried adding  || ' + Masked'  after substr(p_name, 1, instr(p_name, ' ') - 1) .   But this will result in "Alexis + Masked Cruise + Masked" .   Really Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use `regexp_replace`:

```
regexp_replace(<text>,'\s+((\S+$)|(.*(\s+\S+$)))',' xxxx\4')
```

I don't want to go into detail how this exactly works, but you can read any guide about `regular expressions` to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace function get_token 
  (in_str varchar2, in_token varchar2, in_separator varchar2 default ' ') return varchar2
as
begin
  return regexp_substr (in_str, '[^' || in_separator || ']+', 1, in_token);
end;  
/

select get_token('Christopher James Lee',1) || '****' 
         || get_token('Christopher James Lee',3) from dual;
```